# Is it worth it to untrap dart and arrow traps?

Tags: nethack, unnethack

In *UnNetHack*, I know that successfully untrapping an arrow or a dart trap exercises your dexterity.  But doesn't an unsuccessful attempt abuse your dexterity (or worse if you get poisoned)?

I play a lot of *UnNetHack*, where abusing a stat is much more severe than in vanilla *Nethack*.  So I don't want to risk losing stats unless I'm certain that there's a general benefit.

I've never seen anyone address this question before.  Any guesses, educated thoughts, or code-annotated answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vanilla nethack, the answer is generally "Yes".

I'm uncertain about unnethack, but in nethack the only penalty for failing to untrap a dart/arrow trap is damage & the possibility of poison.  Make sure you've got the available HP and, if you're not poison resistant, wear a high MC cloak or mithril armor.

That which does not kill you will exercise your Dex & gain you ammo.

Of course when you stop your untrapping attempts because your HP is below 10, that's when a band of orcs or a mumuk will show up;  that's just how the RNG rolls....

**Edit for 3.6.0**: The increased rarity of MC makes the chance of poison from Dart traps (1/6) more risky.  Arrow Traps, without the chance of poison are still definitely worth it.

Comment: Giving a check, even though no one has dived into the code.  I've been using this technique and haven't seen any ill effects on exercising dexterity. Thanks!